# Flutter: What is the best way to filter Firestore collection items based on user input?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[CASE] 
I have a list of activities stored in a FireStore collection. Each activity has a type. In a dropdown, the user can filter the activities based on their type. There is also an option to select all items.

I currently manage this by passing the activity type to a new widget each time the user changes the value from the dropdown. However, I was wondering if this is the most efficient way of doing this (mainly when scaling up the number of activities in the collection), or if there is a different best practice I should use?

[CODE]

Screen 1: Dropdown and list of activities

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String eventClass;

  final items = ["All", "Music", "Drinks"];

  void _changeClass(selectedClass) {
    eventClass = selectedClass;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        DropdownSearch<String>(
            mode: Mode.BOTTOM_SHEET,
            showSelectedItem: true,
            items: items,
            label: "Change event type",
            onChanged: (String selectedClass) => _changeClass(selectedClass),
            selectedItem: items[0]),
        Expanded(
          child: EventList(eventClass),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Screen2: EventList

```
class EventList extends StatelessWidget {
  final String eventClass;

  EventList(this.eventClass);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('events')
        .where('eventClass', isEqualTo: eventClass.toLowerCase())
        .snapshots();

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data();

            return ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                child: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
              title: Text(data['eventName']),
              subtitle: Text(data['eventDescription']),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => EventItem(data),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your expected upper bound for the number of items in this list, is it finite or infinite?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav It is a finite list

Comment: Posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

ListView constructor is generally used for creating a limited number of items, but in order to create a large list you can use `ListView.builder` constructor. This constructor is appropriate in this scenario as the builder is called only for those items that are actually visible.

The `ListView.builder()` constructor creates items as they’re scrolled onto the screen as opposed to the default ListView constructor, which requires creating all items at once. Please refer to this [document](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists) for more details on this with an interactive example.

> ```
> ListView.builder(
>   itemCount: items.length,
>   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
>    return ListTile(
>       title: Text(items[index]),
>      );
>    },
>  )
> ```